# Laravel package installation There are no commands defined in the "package" namespace

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm currently using: `Laravel Framework 5.6.22`

According to a [package found here](https://github.com/launcher-host/mercurius#2-register-broadcastserviceprovider)

I'm supposed to simply run:

```
composer require launcher/mercurius
```

then

```
php artisan mercurius:install
composer dump-autoload
```

When I run this command I get

```
There are no commands defined in the "mercurius" namespace.
```

Two things I notice:
Package is not added to composer.json file even thou command line says:

```
Using version ^0.0.10 for launcher/mercurius
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
```

I do however see it when I run

```
composer show
launcher/mercurius                 0.0.10    Real-time Messenger package for Laravel
```

Second thing I notice is that the package is not in my vendor folder.

Any idea what's going on her or how I can debug this further?

Comment: After the `composer require launcher/mercurius` command, can you try to run `composer install`?

Comment: I get: Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
@leeman24

Comment: Don't think i'll be able to help but it is odd that your package doesn't get added to `composer.json`. When I start from an empty dir and run `composer require launcher/mercurius` it creates it properly. I also added another package which adds to the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files. Check permissions but i'd expect an error if you cannot write to it.

Comment: Make sure that you are running the command from the root of the Laravel project